# Unable to determine the current HDP while installing spark client on HDP 2.3

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

While deploying the hdp cluster setup using Apache Ambari's Automated setup guide, we encountered the following error at the edge node.

> stderr: 
>   2016-08-08 17:46:03,644 - Could not determine HDP version for component spark-client by calling '/usr/bin/hdp-select status spark-client > /tmp/tmp_vn3OF'. Return Code: 1, Output: .

[click here](https://gist.github.com/Prateek032/3294afbc29b7baa356b63796b1c3f628)to view the complete console log

We also tried Installing Apache Spark on HDP using [this link](http://saptak.in/spark/007-Installing-Spark-1-2.html)